# pgfplots Figure with fixed Width

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dimensions

How can I create a standalone pgfplots figure with set total dimensions, including axis labels and legend entries?

If I set plot dimensions with `width=5cm, height=5cm,` pgfplots only gives me a total figure *approximately* this size. Additionally, if a legend is placed outside the axis box, the legend dimensions are added to the specified dimensions. The manual specifies (**4.10.1 Common Scaling Options**):

> Please note that pgfplots only estimates the size needed for axis- and tick labels. The estimate assumes
> a fixed amount of space for anything which is outside of the axis box. This has the effect that the final
> images may be slightly larger or slightly smaller than the prescribed dimensions.

and further

> If scale only axis=false (the default), pgfplots will **try** to produce the desired width including
> labels, titles and ticks.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
%Grouping
    scale only axis=false,
    height=,
    width=10cm,
%Domain
    xmin=2000, xmax=2020,
    ymode=log,
%Ticks
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
%Axis Labels
    ylabel= Price \text{[}\$(2020)/kg\text{]},
%Legend
    legend cell align={left},
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend style={draw=none},
    legend entries={Entry},
]
\addplot[draw=none] coordinates {(2005,10000)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Below is the visual representation of the solution posted by [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo):

[image]

Comment: I generally use `adjustbox` for plot and legend (if outside of the plot, normally below the plot) separately to manage size/scale.

Comment: There is no telling how big the legend is going to be, so it is not included in the scale calculations.  You could do a trial run in a savebox and compensate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks awful, but it does fit precisely into a 5cm by 5cm rectangle.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}% reducndant
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newsavebox{\temp}

\begin{document}
\savebox{\temp}{\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
%Grouping
    name=border,
    height=5cm,
    width=5cm,
%Domain
    xmin=2000, xmax=2020,
    ymode=log,
%Ticks
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
%Axis Labels
    ylabel= Price \lbrack\$(2020)/kg\rbrack,
%Legend
    legend cell align={left},
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend style={draw=none},
    legend entries={Entry},
]
\addplot[draw=none] coordinates {(2005,10000)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}}% trial

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
%Grouping
    name=border,
    height={\dimexpr 10cm-\ht\temp},
    width={\dimexpr 10cm-\wd\temp},
%Domain
    xmin=2000, xmax=2020,
    ymode=log,
%Ticks
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
%Axis Labels
    ylabel= Price \lbrack\$(2020)/kg\rbrack,
%Legend
    legend cell align={left},
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend style={draw=none},
    legend entries={Entry},
]
\addplot[draw=none] coordinates {(2005,10000)};
\end{axis}
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\draw[green] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle ++(5cm,5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat! I added a visual representation to my question to make it easier to see your solution. I wonder if this could also be done without the need to have the entire figure in a temporary box…?

Comment: Anything which does not affect the size of the plot can be left out.  Otherwise, you really need the whole thing.