# Set real dimensions of pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot colored histogram in `subfigure` environment. But when setting chart dimensions to `\linewidth` I got what follows, which is definitely not what I expect.

[image]

```latex
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        width=\linewidth,
        height=.5\linewidth,
        yticklabels={},
      ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,117)};
        \addplot coordinates {(1,1041)};
        \addplot coordinates {(10,2162)};
        \addplot coordinates {(11,776)};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Histogram of $I_{sc}$}
  \end{subfigure}
```

**How can I force `pgfplots` to occupy all the given space/remove padding/margins/or whatever it is?**

If `scale only axis` used as suggested, margin is still present and chart lands into next subplot.

[image]

Partial solution is to set `ytick=\empty` solves placement problem, but removes ticks entirely...

Comment: When you set `width=X, height=Y`, the dimensions of the axis box itself becomes `(X-45pt)` by `(Y-45pt)`, where 45pt is a hardcoded length `pgfplots` adds to give space for labels. If you add `scale only axis`, the dimensions of  become `X` by `Y`. If adding `scale only axis` isn't enough, you could try https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561201/pgfplots-figure-with-fixed-width/561238#561238 though.

Comment: Is there a way to drop those margins? Scale only axis will result in overflow

Comment: Which margins exactly? Sorry though, I don't have any really good options. A perhaps pragmatic, albeit manual, option is to do e.g. `scale only axis, width=0.98\linewidth,...`

Comment: ehrn scale only axes is on, bottom left corner of chart is in same place and right side gets out of subchart part

Comment: adding `\clip (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth, \linewidth);` hellped in ugly manner

Comment: Yes, I saw that it pokes out the right side a bit, but I didn't get what you meant by "drop those margins". Drop what, where? I'd reduce the width rather than clipping, I think.

Comment: applying `ticks=none` helps a bit. chart is place, but no ticks present :D